# Logout redirects to `/sessiontimeout` instead of `/logout`

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I am sure that this question was asked many times, but I couldn't find one good solution.

When the user clicks on logout, the control is going to `/sessiontimeout` instead of `/logout`. I have seen the different solutions where it was suggested to change the value to `invalidate-session` to `false`. If so, how can we invalidate the session according to the spring standards.

I tried this solution but if we try to login again with the same user, it gives an essence that the previous session still exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="blah.blah.blah" />

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">    
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/sessiontimeout" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/sessionTerminated" access="permitAll" />
            <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
            <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/loginfailed" session-fixation-protection="newSession" invalid-session-url="/sessiontimeout">
                <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" expired-url="/sessionTerminated" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
            </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="infrastructureDataSource" 
                authorities-by-username-query="//query//"
                users-by-username-query="//query//" />
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>

        <authentication-provider ref="authService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="authService" class="blah.blah.blah.blah.AuthServiceImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationHandler" class="blah.blah.blah.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="customApplicationListener" class="blah.blah.blah.CustomApplicationListener" />
</beans:beans>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appContext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appContext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appContext-servlet.xml
                     /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                     /WEB-INF/spring/root-context-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

<!-- some other stuff -->
```

Here, I am implementing the session stealing(If someone logs in with same credentials on a different machine, the existing user must log out) and session timeout as well.

Does any of you have a working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is something like this:

```
<!-- this is the pattern used in order to disable the filters for logout-success-url -->
<http pattern="/login**" security="none"></http> 
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">    
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/sessiontimeout" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As the filters are disabled, how can we invalidate the session and delete cookies.

Comment: Figured out the solution. Thanks @Constantinescu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your logout-success-url="/login" to some other value. If still doesn't work try to exclude logout-success-url from the filter chain ( set security = 'none').

P.S.
I tested your code and it seems that the problem comes from some other config. Can you put all your security configuration file? With your actual configuration I am correctly redirect to logout-success-url.